# Unit circles $O_1$ and $O_2$ are tangent to each other and line $L$; circle $O_n$ is tangent to $O_1$, $O_{n-1}$ and $L$. Find the radius of $O_{20}$

Tags: geometry

> As shown below, circle $O_1$ and $O_2$ have radius 1 and are tangent to each other and line L. Construct $O_3$ such that it is tangent to L, $O_1$, and $O_2$. Suppose $O_n$ is tangent to $O_1$, $O_{n-1}$ and L. What is the radius of $O_{20}$? (Do not use the ["kissing circles" theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem).) 
>   https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/tggz5dg6

I'm having trouble finding a recursive formula. Even so, is the best way to do this bashing out all 17 consecutive radii?

Edit: I'm noticing the radius of $O_n$ is $\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use kissing circles theorem? You can just derive it (or some form of it) as necessary. If you noticed that about $O_n$, try to prove it.

Comment: For $O_3$ there is only one choice (unless you consider parallel lines to be tangent at infinity), but for $O_4$ we have two choices, unless there is a further restriction. One of those choices is $O_2.$ Is there a restriction that each $O_n$ must be distinct from all previous ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the previous circle is never reused as the next circle (that is, $O_{n+1} \neq O_{n-1}$), your formula appears to be correct.

You may have noticed that this is a special case of the "kissing circles" theorem in which one of the curvatures is zero. The instruction "Do not use" presumably means that you have to prove the special case yourself using more elementary knowledge.
Here are some ideas how to do so (leaving you some work to do).

For each $n \geq 1,$ let $r_n$ be the radius of $O_n,$ let $C_n$ be the center of $O_n,$ and let $M_n$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $C_n$ to the line.
For any $n > 1,$ since $O_n$ is tangent to $O_1$ and to the line,
you can use the Pythagorean theorem to find the distance from $C_n$ to the line $C_1M_1$ in terms of $r_n$ alone (no other unknown quantities).

Apply the Pythagorean theorem again to a triangle with hypotenuse $C_nC_{n+1}.$
Deduce a recursive formula from that.

Comment: It is well known that the length of the tangent segment is $2\sqrt{xy}$. I did some work, and derived a formula:
$$2\sqrt{R_n*R_{n-1}}+2\sqrt{R_n}=1-2\sqrt{R_3*R_{4}}-2\sqrt{R_4*R_{5}}-\cdots-2\sqrt{R_{n-2}*R_{n-1}}$$
Am I on the right track?

Comment: Right, what I called "distance to the line $C_1M_1$" is equal to a tangent segment, so I could have saved some unnecessary notation there. I looked at just three tangent segments: between $O_1$ and $O_n$, between $O_n$ and $O_{n-1},$ and between $O_1$ and $O_{n-1}.$

Comment: I see. A much easier recursion would be 
$$2\sqrt{R_n∗R_{n-1}}−2\sqrt{R_n}=2\sqrt{R_{n−1}}$$?

Comment: Yes. Divide everything by $\sqrt{R_nR_{n-1}}$ and it's almost done. It helps that you already have a valid formula and just need to prove it.